# Why is the bot promoting some question?

Tags: support

I saw that a post of mine raised in the feed because "Community Bot modified yesterday". However I cannot see any edits? What does this mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what the Community User does.

One of its purposes, described [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19738/236563), is to bump unanswered questions to the front page in the hope of getting them answered.
The process is described in detail on the Main Meta:-
[What can cause a question to be bumped?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/48578/236563)

Comment: I note that my first question here garnered no answers for a time, and then, when the bot boosted it, it did.  So it works.